# Problem with exporting/importing React component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a React component for a navigation bar.

This component I'd like to import from a separate file into my App.js.
Currently, the component should just return a simple 'Hello world' paragraph, but I have trouble getting this to work.

I have written the following code into a file located at src/components/navbar.js:

```
import React from 'react';

export default class navBar extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <p>Hello world.</p>
        )
    }
}
```

Now I'd like to import this component from my src/App.js, which looks like this:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './App.css';

import navBar from './components/navbar.js'

class App extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <navBar/>
        );
    }
}

export default App;
```

If I compile and open the site, nothing's there, which confuses me.

I'd be very thankful for any help!

EDIT:
It's been suggested that the problem is that `<App />` is not being rendered anywhere. I don't believe that's the case, since there's another file being created by default (index.js), which looks like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I have also tried putting the paragraph (and the entire navbar) directly into src/App.js.

After compiling I could see the expected results in the browser, so the problem should lie with the exporting/importing.

Comment: How do you compile the site? How do you run the server? Is there anything in the console?

Comment: Is this the entire code you have? Because if so `<App />` isn't rendered into the DOM anywhere. Edit: use capital names for components: `<NavBar />`

Comment: @Aurel Bílý I'm using JetBrains' WebStorm to compile and run. I created a new project and chose React App as project type. There's nothing in the console.

Comment: Try using https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app instead

Comment: @Chris G Sorry I should have mentioned that, there's an index.js file that's being created by default. There the <App /> is imported and rendered with ReactDOM as far as I understand. I'll add this to the question in a sec.

Comment: how are you "opening the site"? Is there a build folder? is there a dev server?

Comment: The issue is you need to replace `navBar` with `NavBar` in App.js

Comment: @Chris G I didn't know that would make a difference. Thank you very much, I've struggled far too long with this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In JSX, lower case tags are considered to be simple HTML/SVG elements. You can use lower case only if you use accessors (so with a dot like `bla.blabla`).

You can read about it [here](https://gist.github.com/sebmarkbage/f1f4ba40816e7d7848ad) for example.

So in your case you must change the class name `navBar` to `NavBar` and then in the render method:

```
render() {
        return (
            <NavBar/>
        );
    }
```

Comment: I'm pretty new to JS and had no idea this would make any difference.
Thank you very much, it works now!

Comment: @pfincent JS doesn't care; React does.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a full working example: 
** Note: NavBar.js shoud start with a Capital letter.

App.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import NavBar from "./components/NavBar";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <NavBar />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, rootElement);
```

NavBar.js

```
import React from "react";

export default class NavBar extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <p>Hello world.</p>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```